# How can I forward a section of a WhatsApp conversation?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, instant-messaging

Suppose I had this conversation with someone on WhatsApp, consisting of several messages going back-and-forth. Now, I would like to forward that exchange to someone else...

1. on WhatsApp
2. via a plain-textu representation (which still makes it clear who says what, and isn't just a concatenation of the text)
3. via some reasonable structural represntation, doesn't matter exavtly which (e.g. XML, HTML, markdown, RDF, email-like quoting etc.)

Which of these options is feasible, and how?

PS - I use a Doogee X5 phone with Android 5.1, in case it matters.

Answer (score 0):

Take Screenshots !!!
Works for everything !

Comment: That's not such a bad idea... but the WhatsApp interface doesn't seem to offer to let me do that. So, how do I take screenshots in WhatsApp?

Comment: Standard way: Hold Power+Volume Down

Comment: @GokulNC: That doesn't work for me, at least not with my Doogee X5.

Comment: Try **[Screenshot Easy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.screenshoteasy)** app..

Answer (score 0):

Simply *copy* multiple  chats and *paste* to the third person . You will have time and sender information as shown below in the screenshot

[image]

In response to comment asking *how to copy*, simply long press the chat (S) and copy highlighted chat using the icon pointed. Next, to paste, in another chat, long press and you get the *paste* option

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "copy multiple chats"? How do I do that?

Comment: Explained that in answer

Comment: Haven't seen your response? Wondering if you had issues?